# Unexpected output when filtering Python list: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, list, logic, filtering, sequence

I am trying to filter a list, here is the code:

```
 test=['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','footer','header']

 def rm_hf(x): return x != 'footer'

 filter(rm_hf,test)
```

Results in :

```
>>>['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','header']
```

That is expected result, finding 'footer' in the list and remove it.

Now I want to remove both 'header' and 'footer' so I do this:

```
 test2=['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','footer','header']

 def rm_hf2(x): return x != 'footer' or x != 'header'

 filter(rm_hf2,test2)
```

Results in :

```
>>>['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','footer','header']
```

Now that's weird, it just gives out both 'footer','header' instead of filtering them?

What did I do wrong? I think my logic is correct...

Comment: -1: Trivial logic question muddied up with "weird behavior" and "bug in Python".  It's always logic.  How hard can it be to test `rm_hf2`?

Comment: Well , i just asked question clearly ,  You just vote me down instead of correcting me , wow , what an expert LOL. I can't stop laughing.Well i dont care votes here anyways , so enjoy voting me down :)

Comment: The correction is the point.  The downvote doesn't fix the question to help other people to learn from your question.  Please actually test your `rm_hf2` function.  Please post the results of testing your `rm_hf2` function to make the question understandable to other people.

Comment: +1 vote to you as you love votes :). do you see the result of rm_hf2?>>>['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','footer','header']
 lol.. , Anyways , thanks for voting me down , other people gives me clear and productive answers. Thats way a lot more valuable than votes :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your logic is correct because you think like a human. Your computer does not. He reads every element from your list, then stumbles upon 'footer'. "Is footer different than footer?", he says. "NO! It's the same string! It's evaluated to false. Let's see the next condition". "Is footer different than header? YES!" The condition is therefore `False or True`, which obviously evaluates to true.

You want a `and`, not a `or` :

```
def rm_hf2(x): return x != 'footer' and x != 'header'
```

You could also use a tuple and the `in` keyword, which is more readable :

```
def rm_hf2(x): return x not in ('footer', 'header')
```

It's important that you understand what's really going on with "and" and "or", though. And let's be honest : if something isn't working as you think it should, the problem most likely lies in your own code, and not in Python language itself.

Comment: Here is another explanation for the logical error: He thought he wrote `not (x=='footer' or x=='header')` but wrote `(not x=='footer') or (not x=='header')` instead.

Comment: @THC4k: It's possible, although it's a common beginner mistake to write `or` when you mean "shouldn't be any of those".

Comment: Another explanation: He didn't read the filter function he wrote INCLUSIVE_OR he didn't TEST the filter function he wrote.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, i was thinking the way what THC4K saids!

Comment: + it is my first time using filter too.

Answer (score 4):

> my logic is correct

Actually, no it isn't, as highlighted in other answers.

A far neater way to achieve the desired outcome is to use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), *viz*:

```
test = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'footer', 'header']
undesirable = ['footer', 'header']
[_ for _ in test if _ not in undesirable]
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]` if `function` is not `None` and `[item for item in iterable if item]` if `function` is `None`.

That said, there's no time like the present to brush-up on your [Boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic)!

Were you to unit test your code, you would quickly find out that your second filtration function is not doing what you expect. Here is a simplistic example:

```
$ cat 4281875.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

def rm_hf2(x): return x != 'footer' or x != 'header'

class test_rm_hft(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_aaa_is_not_filtered(self):
        self.assertTrue(rm_hf2('aaa'))

    def test_footer_is_filtered_out(self):
        self.assertFalse(rm_hf2('footer'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


$ ./4281875.py 
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_footer_is_filtered_out (__main__.test_rm_hft)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./4281875.py", line 13, in test_footer_is_filtered_out
    self.assertFalse(rm_hf2('footer'))
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

What everybody else said, plus:

When you have several items that you want to exclude, use a `set` instead of a chain of `and`s or a `tuple`:

```
# do once
blacklist = set(['header', 'footer'])

# as needed
filter(lambda x: x not in blacklist, some_iterable)
```

Rationale: Looking through a `tuple` takes time proportional to the position of the found item; failure takes the same time as the last item. Looking up an item in a set takes the same time for all items, and for failure. Sets usually win for a large number of items. It all depends on the probability that each item will be searched, and what the probability of failure is. Tuples can win even with a large collection when there's a high probability of a few items (they should be put at the front of the tuple) and a low chance of failure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used lists when comparing in list comprehension. I should changed  to sets. These list are big , they are list of files which have 20k + items.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a list comprehension instead of filter.

```
test = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','footer','header']
filtered_test = [x for x in test if x not in ('footer', 'header')]
```

or a generator expression (depending on your needs)

```
test = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','footer','header']
filtered_test = (x for x in test if x not in ('footer', 'header'))
```

Comment: yes i just have just used list comprehensions. But thought filter is more readable , and i tired filters , it is first time using filter. , i dont usually use filters or maps , just list comprehensions

Comment: @V3ss0n This is why you should stick with comprehensions -  precisely because they are easier to read and understand!